# Vercel API Throttling Limit

Tags: vercel

Is there a possibility to set an API limit for a specific endpoint in Vercel?.

I am Building an Next.js Application for a certain endpoint I want to limit the number of incoming request from the user's is there a possibility to do it?

Is there a predefined solution from vercel?

Comment: Check https://vercel.com/new/templates/next.js/api-rate-limit-upstash

Comment: @paulogdm, Thanks. But is there any upper limit within vercel for any api that is created.
Example: If I have an API which is built using Next.js

Comment: Also, does web-client in vercel have API Gateway or rate-limiting feature?

Comment: There are limits for concurrency (you don't want to hit that at all): https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#serverless-function-concurrency
Any custom limits needs to be handled by your own code.